# Malus law for gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, field-theory, gravitational-waves, polarization

What is the analogue of the Malus law for polarized electromagnetic waves to the cause of plus and cross polarized gravitational waves?

Bonus: What if gravitational waves have further degrees of polarization like those in modified gravitational theories?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is similar, except the fact that the gravitational waves are described by (in linearised General Relativity) a $2x2$ transverse tensor perturbation means the two polarisation states are rotated by only 45 degrees with respect to each other. This would lead to a $\cos^2 2\theta$ Malus' law if we could detect gravitational wave intensity, and $\cos 2\theta$ for amplitude.

For example, if an "L-shaped" interferometer is "illuminated" from directly overhead by an unpolarised gravitational wave source, then only one of the polarisation states will induce a response in the interferometer.

If the gravitational waves are "linearly" polarised (i.e. consist of only one of the two polarisation states) then the response will be modified by $\cos {\bf 2}\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between one of the detector axes and the polarisation axis of the gravitational wave.

Note that since the detectors are sensitive to amplitude, rather than intensity, the response goes as $\cos 2\theta$ rather than $\cos^2 2\theta$.

In other gravitational theories then there may be modes in addition to the tranverse tensor modes of General Relativity, including scalar transverse waves or scalar longitudinal waves. As an example, consider the following diagram illustrating the displacement of a ring of test masses by various possible polarisation modes (taken from a thesis by [Fesik 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09505.pdf)).

[image: GW polarisation modes]

(a) and (b) are the familiar transverse tensor plus and cross polarisations, (c) is a scalar transverse polarisation and (d) is a scalar longitudinal polarisation. Note the waves travel through the screen for (a), (b) and (c) but from left to right for (d).

Clearly if there was power in mode (c) then that would change the angular response of a detector - there would be no difference in response if the detector (or source) were rotated. I think the same is true, but less obviously for mode (d). There can also be a difference in the response as a function of the direction to the source. This would enable a network of detectors, that could locate the source direction, to say something about the relative contributions of these polarisation modes.

Comment: I am searching for a formula like the Malus one...